# xml parsing with constant memory usage

Tags: c++, xml, memory, xpath, xqilla

i am trying to find xml parser with xpath support that uses small amount of memory , or rather constant amount of memory , i am trying to parse large xml files , like almost 1 Giga , i have been reading about xqilla , and it seems that is uses very large amount of memory because it is dom based, correct me if i'm wrong..
anyways , any idea for such xml parser for C++ & linux ?

Comment: You'd better add c++ tag also

Answer (score 1):

If you can process the XML in essentially a single pass, a SAX parser would be a good idea. How about Apache [Xerces C++](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/)?

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that. But if you drop your XPath requirement and write your own code to select the data you require, you should be able to use SAX.

Comment: @user687543: Why can't a SAX parser support XPath?

Answer (score 1):

Saxon-EE supports streaming of large XML documents using XSLT or XQuery (streaming is better supported in XSLT than in XQuery). Details at

- [Streaming of Large Documents](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/sourcedocs/streaming/)

Answer (score 0):

You might look at

> **pugixml** enables very fast, convenient and memory-efficient XML document processing. However, since pugixml has a DOM parser, it can't process XML documents that do not fit in memory; also the parser is a non-validating one, so if you need DTD/Schema validation, the library is not for you

However, it is explicitely not a streaming parser. I know streaming and xpath do not generally jive well (due to potential random-access requirements). Allthough, in .NET the **[ever-famous XPathReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465237/what-ever-happened-to-xpathreader)** seemed to have bridged the gap for a popular subset of XPath :)