# Using XMLTextReader, how can I tell which element I am on?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

This is what my code looks like:

```
case "Creator":
    br.Read();
    br.MoveToContent();  // gives the content of the role
    tbComposer.Text = br.Value;
    br.Read();
    br.MoveToContent();  // gives the content of the role
    tbConductor.Text = br.Value;
    br.Read();
    br.MoveToContent();  // gives the content of the role
    tbOrchestra.Text = br.Value;
    break;
```

This is the working code: (Thanks everybody for your input... couldn't have done it without you!)  Spokane-Dude

```
                case "Creator":
                    br.MoveToFirstAttribute();
                    if (br.Value == "Composer") {
                        br.Read();
                        tbComposer.Text = br.Value;
                    }
                    if (br.Value == "Conductor") {
                        br.Read();
                        tbConductor.Text = br.Value;
                    }
                    if (br.Value == "Orchestra") {
                        br.Read();
                        tbOrchestra.Text = br.Value;
                    }
                    break;
```

This is what my XML looks like:

```
<ItemLookupResponse>
    <OperationRequest/>
    <Items>
        <Request/>
        <Item>
            <ItemAttributes>
                <Binding>Audio CD</Binding>
                <CatalogNumberList>
                    <CatalogNumberListElement>43850</CatalogNumberListElement>
                </CatalogNumberList>
                <Creator Role="Composer">Gioachino Rossini</Creator>
                <Creator Role="Conductor">Riccardo Chailly</Creator>
                <Creator Role="Orchestra">National Philharmonic Orchestra</Creator>
            </ItemAttributes>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</ItemLookupResponse>
```

I need to know if I am reading the element **Creator Role="Composer"** or **Creator Role="Conductor"**, etc

So, using XMLTextReader, how can I determine what the element text is?

Comment: The XML you posted is invalid. Please post the actual XML, or at least a small example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: .NET is 3.5... how do I post the XML (it's about 50 lines...

Comment: What do you mean? Post it in  your question, select it, then press Control-K to indent it all by four characters so it's treated like code.

Comment: Hey John... Sorry... I need to move it into an editor... do you want me to do that, or can you kinda see what's going on?

Comment: Gotta go for tonight... be back early in the morning... thanks for the help so far...

Comment: See my edit. Pretty-printed, and irrelevant content removed.

Comment: Thanks John... I thought I implied that I can't guarantee that all three Role's are going to be there...that's why I needed to see where I was.

Comment: Please tell us what you're trying to accomplish. XmlReader is almost certainly not what you want to use. In particular what do you want to see if one of the roles is not present? Since you're using .NET 3.5, you should probably be using LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this sample ?  I hope it would useful to you

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string xmlStr = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><Creators><Creator Role=\"Composer\">Gioachino Rossini</Creator><Creator Role=\"Conductor\">Riccardo Chailly</Creator><Creator Role=\"Orchestra\">National Philharmonic Orchestra</Creator></Creators>";
        using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlTextReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlStr)))
        {
            xmlReader.MoveToContent();
            xmlReader.ReadStartElement("Creators" , "");
            SomeMethod("Composer", xmlReader);
            SomeMethod("Conductor", xmlReader);
            SomeMethod("Orchestra", xmlReader);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("........");
        Console.Read();
    }

    static void SomeMethod(string role, XmlReader xmlReader)
    {
        xmlReader.MoveToAttribute("Role");

        switch (role)
        {
            case "Composer":
                {
                    xmlReader.MoveToContent();
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Composer:{0}", xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString()));

                } break;
            case "Conductor":
                {
                    xmlReader.MoveToContent();
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Conductor:{0}", xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString()));

                } break;
            case "Orchestra":
                {
                    xmlReader.MoveToContent();
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Orchestra:{0}", xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString()));

                } break;

            default: break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't until its actually read. XmlTextReader reads a stream, sequentially.

So it is rather the other way around: you can know what element you had when you reach the attribute `Role="Composer"`.

Consider using XPath, LINQ-To-XML or similar: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156083.aspx

```
node.XPathSelectElement(@"*/Creator[@Role=""Conductor""]");
```

For XmlTextReader there is a XPathReader component somewhere:

- [What ever happened to XPathReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465237/what-ever-happened-to-xpathreader)

Comment: Here's my code:

 '                       case "Creator":
                            br.Read();
                            br.MoveToContent();  // gives the content of the role
                            tbComposer.Text = br.Value;
                            br.Read();
                            br.MoveToContent();  // gives the content of the role
                            tbConductor.Text = br.Value;
                            br.Read();
                            br.MoveToContent();  // gives the content of the role'

Comment: Could you update the question instead? Reading that comment made my head hurt :)

Comment: Put that in your question, not in a comment